# An elaboration of a part in the proof of a criterion for finding Carmichael numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruence-relations

The criteria and its proof is given below:

[image]

[image]

But I do not understand why $p_{i} - 1|n-1$ implies $p_{i} | a^{n-1} - 1$ if we know that $p_{i} | a^{p_{i}-1} -1$. could anyone explain this for me please ?

Comment: $p-1\mid n-1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large p-1}-1\mid a^{\large n-1}-1\ \ $

Comment: Or: $\ n\!-\!1 = (p\!-\!1)k$ $\,\Rightarrow\,\bmod p\!:\,\ a^{\large n-1}\equiv (a^{\large p-1})^k\equiv 1^{\large k}\equiv 1\ \ $

Comment: Btw, "discrepancy" is not correct. Better would be "explanation" or "elaboration".

Comment: I corrected it @BillDubuque

Comment: for the first comment I am not convinced with it, is there a proof?

Comment: For the second comment .... I can not see how it substitutes the first one ..... could you elaborate further please?

Comment: The hurdles you face in this and your prior questions seems to indicate that you may have jumped ahead too quickly to more advanced topics before mastering the basics. Did you perchance dive into the middle of a book on elementary number theory before reading the prior sections?

Comment: yes .... I am working from elementary number theory for David Burton @BillDubuque

Comment: I am sorry I have corrected it @bof

Comment: Got it from your second comment @BillDubuque .....  sorry for my stupidness :(